# How to extract one single row in code igniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can someone show me how to pass data to the a view when it's extracted from the database via the model (which returns a single row) :

my sample code

```
function read_article($article_name)
{
    $data['row'] = $this->user_model->extract_article($article_name);
    $this->load->view('user/view_article',$data);
}
  // controller code ^^^^^^^^^
function extract_article($article_name)
{
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('col1,col2,col3,col4');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('col4'=>$article_name))->result();
    foreach($query as $s)
    {
        $data[] = $s;
    }
    $data;
}
```

// model code ^^^^^^^^^^

```
foreach($row as $r)
{
echo "<h1>".$r->col2."</h1>";
echo "<p>".$r->col3."</p>";
}
```

// view code ^^^^^^^^^

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: user/view_article.php

Line Number: 52

Comment: Abd what have you tried many time, huh?

Comment: `Give me...` WOW, somebody is awfully demanding.

Comment: "pardon me" i'm bad with english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTM](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $row = $query->row(); 

   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```